# Get Output Parameter Value in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a stored procedure with an OUTPUT parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProcedure]
    (@myValue NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @myValue = (SELECT myValue FROM myTable WHERE something = 1)
    SElECT @myValue;
END
```

My C# class:

```
public string getOutPut()
{
    string shortFooter;
    string sql = "myStoredProcedure";
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand DBCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, DBConn))
        {
            try
            {
                DBConn.Open();

                DBCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter newSqlParam = new SqlParameter();
                newSqlParam.ParameterName = "@myValue";
                newSqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                newSqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                DBCmd.Parameters.Add(newSqlParam);

                DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                shortFooter = DBCmd.Parameters["@myValue"].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string blah = ex.ToString();
                shortFooter = "";
            }
        }
    }

    return shortFooter;
}
```

This is the exception that I'm getting:

> System.InvalidOperationException: String[0]: the Size property has an
>   invalid size of 0.

What I don't understand is, I have used this code before, except that in the stored procedure I'm getting the value of the output with `IDENTITY()` when I create a new record in the database, so the parameter type in the class is INT. But in concept it should be the same, but I guess I'm wrong, just don't know why.

What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: the `SElECT @myValue;` in the query is useless on a `DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the size required to hold the output value. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> For output parameters with a variable length type (nvarchar, for example), the size of the parameter defines the size of the buffer holding the output parameter.

Set the [`Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the output parameter in your code to match what's in the stored procedure:

```
newSqlParam.Size = 100;
```

The default value is 0, which is what's causing the exception.